# Invalid syntax with barplot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

[image]

I have created `cat_num` to implement a barplot for every column at once in `df_cat`. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is with the syntax even though I referred to the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the error that you are getting? Moreover, you must create a minimal reproducible example for community members to quickly look at your implementation. (not a screenshot with several columns).

Comment: Isn't the cause of the error the lack of a `)` at the end of the print statement?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to fix your brackets:

```
print("graph for %s: total = %d" % (i,len(cat_num)))
```

You did not close the `print` statement with a final bracket.

Some advice for you:
The error tells you up to which point the code reached before having a problem. In this case, you can see the code ran up to the line 4 (`chart = ...`). Therefore, your first step should be to check line 4 and just before line 4 to see if you can spot anything amiss.